# ECS docker container cpu and memory size

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I'm using AWS ECS for deploy docker-compose.

In my docker container, one nginx and one flask server is running.

[image]

Also I will use c4.large instance.

[image]

In my case, How much should I allocate `cpu_shares` and `mem_limit` for each image?

I know that there is no exact answer.

But I want to know if in my case, what is general percentage.

Or, any suggestion, will be useful for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Run your both servers on the local machine using Docker.
Check the Resource cpu_shares and mem_limit allocation with this command

> docker stats

This will provide you with all the details. Then, set the same Limits for your ECS Task.

Here is an example:
[image: Docker run nginx]

After running this we can check the stats using the command as provided earlier.
[image: Docker Stats]